# Can we use The Modal verb 'Will' to express a possibility?

Tags: modal-verbs

For example-
Maybe she won't come to our party.

Comment: Remove "maybe" and the example now reads "**She won't come to our party**" nothing hesitant or uncertain in that statement. Quite the opposite in fact! The person either stoutly refuses to attend to the party or the speaker is making a (pessimistic?) prediction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "maybe" and the example now reads

> "She won't come to our party"

There is nothing hesitant or uncertain in that statement. Quite the opposite in fact, "she" either stoutly refuses to attend the party or the speaker is making a (pessimistic?) prediction.

1. I won't do it!

(I refuse to do it)

2. Maybe I won't do it

(I might not do it)

To express uncertainty in the future, you can use the modal verb ***might***

“**She might come to our party**”

> Like **wouldn't** for past situations, **won't** can be used to talk about **refusal** when it relates to present situations:
>
> - I can't get these pictures to download. I keep clicking on this icon, but they won't download.
> - It's no good trying to persuade him. He won't go and that's that.

Source: *BBC Learning English*
[Wouldn't/would & won't/will for refusals and insistence](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv340.shtml)

Comment: would you please explain this to me?1.I will go to the park tomorrow.2.I will definitely go to the park tomorrow.Does the two sentences shows different level of certainty?

Comment: "Definitely" is used for emphasis, it leaves out any lingering hesitancy or doubt.

Answer (score 1):

We often use *will* in predictions of future events :

e.g., *Tomorrow will be warm, with some cloud in the afternoon.*

Moreover, the adverb **Maybe** (*=perhaps*) has been used in your example to show the **possibility** :

*Maybe she won't come to our party.*